# coldfusion remove unnecessary output

Tags: coldfusion

I have an output page like this

```
<!-- some css -->
<!-- some js -->

the body of content is here
```

unfortunatelly the **css** & **js** is **always included before** content body. how can we remove the **css** and **js** so the output is just content body?

I can't change the way how **css** & **js** rendered in the page because it's part of the framework

thank you

Comment: Don't use ColdFusion ;) Just kidding. Need a little more information on what is getting output.

Comment: I want the output is in json. if I use jQuery when call the ajax page, I know I can use $.ajax({dataType: 'text'}) and remove css & js from the output and convert the text (json) to a json object

Comment: **Which framework are you using?** All the standard frameworks provide a way to change layout, so you have a regular layout with HTML head that outputs CSS+JS, but also a blank layout for JSON (which doesn't), and you switch between them as appropriate.

Comment: it's my company framework, we using it for internal application only

Comment: Then fix it to allow multiple layouts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place a <cfcontent reset="true" /> right before your content. That'll flush the output buffer.

Comment: This will work (good idea to set `type="text/json"` also), but the better solution is to use different layouts to avoid the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Are the CSS / JS in between `<head></head>`?  If so, do a cross-file search (like.. using Eclipse) to search for all .cfc & .cfm files for `<cfhtmlheader>`.

FYI, if you use `<cfform>` or other ajax tags from CF8+, CF will inject some css and JS on the top of the page...

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
<cfsetting enableCFoutputOnly = "Yes">
```

On the top of the page.
Then use `<cfoutput></cfoutput>` whenever you want output.

For ColdFusion, it's CFML reference helps us a lot.

Take a look on [that](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/6.1/htmldocs/tags-pc6.htm).

Comment: You linked to what is possibly the *oldest* documentation that's still online for ColdFusion! You can always find the latest docs at: http://help.adobe.com